# file_get_contents not working as expected but curl works fine.

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have tested file_get_contents on my server and it works for almost all website and fails for this particular link below but works on http://phpfiddle.org/

```
<?php

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.kinopoisk.ru/picture/10006/');
echo $homepage;

?>
```

I have tested this link http://www.kinopoisk.ru and it works for my server as well and I checked logs and there is no log for that link. As the homepage is opening its very much clear that file_get_contents is not disabled at both site (my site and that site) so if anyone can figure out the issue why it is not working in my page it will be great.
I tried curl also and the same blank output. No error nothing.

```
<?php

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.kinopoisk.ru/picture/10006/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

?>
```

Comment: Does `ini_set('user_agent','whatever?');` work for the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your two code snippets.

In the snippet where your code uses curl the HTTP Request Headers look as follows.

```
GET /picture/10006/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Your application name
Host: www.kinopoisk.ru
Accept: */*
```

In the snippet where your code uses file_get_contents the HTTP Request headers look as follows.

```
GET /picture/10006/ HTTP/1.0
Host: www.kinopoisk.ru
```

What this illustrates is that the webserver at www.kinopoisk.ru is not responding if a User-Agent and Accept-Header are not set. I changed your first code example to the following and it now works.

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept: */*i\r\n" .
              "User-Agent: Your application name\r\n"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.kinopoisk.ru/picture/10006/',0, $context);
print_r($homepage);
```

By looking at the response headers I could see the server at www.kinopoisk.ru is using Nginx and is most likely configured to not return a response when Accept and User-Agent headers not set.

Answer (score 0):

solved using curl but i still dont know why file_get_contents works in one server and not in other server

```
<?php

$curl_handle=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.kinopoisk.ru/picture/10006/');
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
  $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);


 echo $query;
  ?>
```